# WPF: Cannot resolve symbols in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Hi I'm trying to learn a bit of WPF and C# for a project I'm working on. I realised after working for a while that I was going to use couple of the same item and I thought it would be fitting to create my own class to make it easier to use. However now I can't reference elements defined in the XAML in the code behind like I could when just doing it in a window. The error I get is "Cannot resolve symbol 'ThaButton" in the ContactPanel.xaml.cs:

```
using System.Windows.Controls; 

namespace WPF_OOM
{
    public partial class ContactPanel : ContentControl
    {
        public Contact Person { get; set; }
        public ContactPanel()
        {
            ThaButton.Content = "test";
        }
    }
}
```

My ContactPanel.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="WPF_OOM.ContactPanel:UserControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <DockPanel x:Name="dp">
        <TextBlock x:Name="NameTextBlock" Text="testtesttest" DockPanel.Dock="Left"></TextBlock>
        <Button x:Name="ThaButton" Content="button" DockPanel.Dock="Right"></Button>
    </DockPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Hopefully I've explained my problem well enough. I might have taken the wrong approach to this problem, let me know if there's a better way.

Cheers

Comment: the x:Class attribute seems problematic: `<UserControl x:Class="WPF_OOM.ContactPanel:UserControl"`, should be `<UserControl x:Class="WPF_OOM.ContactPanel`.

Comment: You class Definiton in xaml is off "WPF_OOM.ContactPanel:UserControl".
Please also consider reading about the mvvm Pattern. Normally, you would not be doing stuff like this.

Comment: I had same issue. I solved it by restarting VS.

Answer (score 0):

Remove *:UserControl* from *x:Class="WPF_OOM.ContactPanel:UserControl"* so it looks like **x:Class="WPF_OOM.ContactPanel"**

Also in your code behind you have the ContactPanel inheriting form ContentControl, but in your xaml it inherits from UserControl. These base classes must match. So change them both to be UserControl or ContentControl

It looks like you created a separate .cs file? I would recommend working with the code behind generated with the xaml file. One way to get to it is in the xaml editor right-click and choose 'View code'. If you imported the xaml and .cs file then reloading the project or restarting visual studio should combine them again in solution explorer if they are not already.

I would suggest looking into the Model-View-ViewModel or MVVM pattern. It works rather nice with WPF ;)

Hope this helps get you started.